# Jackson exception after Ajax call in Spring/hibernate web-app

Tags: ajax, spring, hibernate, jackson, sessionfactory

in my spring web-app and behind an AJAX call the below exception fire :

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.domain.entities.Person.followerd, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Parent entity:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="follower")
 @JsonIgnore
 private List<FollowerPerson> followerd;
 ....

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name="phone", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="person"))
protected List<Phone> phones;
}
```

FollowerPerson entity

```
@Entity
public class FollowerPerson implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private FollowerPk id;

    @MapsId("std")
    @ManyToOne
    private Person std;

    @MapsId("follower")
    @ManyToOne
    private Person follower;
....
}
```

in My AppConfig i use this txManager spring + hibernate (JPA-based):

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager txManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(
            getEntityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
    return jpaTransactionManager;
}
```

the exception occur when the ajax call try to recognise the list after findAll dao method execution that looks for all persons

When i annotate this attribute with fetch=FetchType.EAGER
an other exception instead will appear :

```
cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags: [com.domain.entities.Person.followerd, com.domain.entities.Person.phones]
```

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change list to set if you can. LinkedHashSet if you still need an order.